# facing build failed when running demandware project on eclipse from mac 10.12.06

Tags: demandware

error:-
check-node:
styles:
[echo] Running gulp build task for Mac OS X in /Users/admin/Documents/.../gulp_builder
[exec] env: node: No such file or directory
BUILD FAILED
/Users/admin/Documents/.../gulp_builder/builders.xml:84: exec returned: 127

Total time: 193 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to not having Gulp or some dependent component installed on the PATH being used by Eclipse. Without seeing more about your gulp_builder/builders.xml document I can't really comment as to what is missing. Can you post more context such as the 5 lines before and after and including line 84 of `builders.xml`

Comment: thanks I found the cause of this error Its due to PATH used in eclipse.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer correct if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @sholsinger that more info would be better, but you may want to double-check that you have all of the node modules installed.  You could run "npm install" in the terminal when you are in the directory where your package.json lives.